# Testing nested promises in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, async-await, jestjs

I'm having trouble testing the following function in Jest. I have a function that can either take an array or a promise as an argument. Either way, I pass that argument to an axios call, the only difference is if the argument is a promise, I call `.then()` before passing it to the call.

This all works fine and dandy, but I'm having trouble writing unit tests to confirm this is working.

`sendItems.js`

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const saveItems = () => {
  return axios({
    url: '/stuff/graphql',
    method: 'post',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    data: {
      whatever: 'yo'
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      return response
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return err
    })
}
export const sendItems = items => {

  if(items instanceof Promise){
    items.then(result => {
      return saveItems(result)
    })
      .catch(err => {
        return err
      })
  }
  else{
    return saveItems(items)
  }
}

export default { sendItems, saveItems }
```

And the test looks like this:

```
/* global jest, describe, beforeAll, beforeEach, expect, test */
import axios from 'axios'
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'

describe('save items', () => {
  let sendItems, mock, items

  beforeAll(() => {
    sendItems = require('../services/sendItems.js').sendItems
    mock = new MockAdapter(axios)
    items = [
      {
        pid: '1',
        name: 'shoe'
      }
    ]
  })

  test('returns 200 when the call to save items is successful', async () => {
    const response = {
      status: 200,
      data: 'success'
    }
    mock.onPost('stuff/graphql').reply(200, response)
    const sendItemsResp = await sendItems(items)
    expect(sendItemsResp.data.status).toEqual(response.status)
  })

  test('correctly resolves the value of input passed to the service, if it is a Promise', async() => {
    const response = {
      status: 200,
      data: 'success'
    }

    items = Promise.resolve([{"p": 1}, {"p": 2}])

    mock.onPost('stuff/graphql').reply(200, response)

    const sendItemsResp = await sendItems(items)
    expect(sendItemsResp.response.status).toEqual(response.status)
    // expect(saveItems).toHaveBeenCalledWith([{"p": 1}, {"p": 2}])
  })
})
```

The earlier test in which I pass an array to `sendItems` passes, but the latter test in which I pass a Promise to `sendItems` fails due to the fact that `sendItemsResp` is undefined. If I put a `console.log(saveItems(result)` in the `sendItems` function when running the latter test, I get a pending promise, so I am assuming that I need to some how make that promise resolve in this test. However, I do not know how to do this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing a `return` statement in `items.then(result => {`

Also, you can probably do `const sendItems = items => Promise.resolve(items).then(saveItems)`

The `.then` and `.catch` are redundant too.

Comment: Can't believe I missed the `return` statement. I wonder why this was working locally? I don't understand your latter comment of doing `const sendItems = items => Promise.resolve(items).then(saveItems)`. Where would I put that and what would it get me?

Comment: It would replace the entire `sendItems` method, just a shorter version of it.

Explanation: `sendItems` always returns a `Promise`, and this shorter version makes it work for both use cases.

when items is an `Array`, it becomes `Promise.resolve([]).then()` and when it's already a `Promise`, it'd be `Promise.resolve(Promise.resolve([])).then()`, which will yield the same results.